# Android webview in background - no autokill

Tags: android, service, webview, background

i've write a simple app, is a simple webview activity. I need that the music of the html page remains in the background and is not kill. how can I do? I read to use a service, but I can not do it. give me a help?

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Instead, you could use a webscraping library such as Jsoup to extract the link to the audio you want to play from the webpage, and then download the audio file and play it in a background service with your own code.